# trouble publishing my first artifact on gradle

Tags: gradle, repository, artifactory, nexus

I am having trouble pushing my first build to gradle to a remote server on nexus. The build was successful but when i use ./gradlew publish no jar files are pushed to the repo.

below is my build code

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.2.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.8.RELEASE'
}

group 'com.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

publishing {
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            artifact("build/libs/my-app-$version"+".jar") {
                extension 'jar'
            }}
        }
    }

    repositories {
        maven {
            name 'nexus'
            url "http://159.65.23.158:8081/repository/maven-snapshots/"
            credentials {
                username project.repoUser
                password project.repoPassword

            }
        }
    }

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation group: 'net.logstash.logback', name: 'logstash-logback-encoder', version: '5.2'
    testImplementation group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}
```

When I entered the ./gradlew publish it performs the same as the ./gradlew build command. I have checked the nexus repo and no files have been pushed to my repo. I am doing a bootcamp by Nana Janashia and I have followed step by step and cannot figure where i am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the publishing task does not depend on the jar task, so no jar has been produced to get picked up from the libs folder. You can confirm this by running `./gradlew publish --dry-run` to see what tasks are running.

To fix this, I suggest you pass the appropriate jar task to the `artifact` method instead of the raw path to the jar, viz:

```
publishing {
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            artifact(tasks.named(sourceSets.main.jarTaskName)) {
                extension 'jar'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Passing the task gives Gradle the information it needs to run the right tasks in the right order.

Answer (score 0):

It was not working for me too, because the repository you're trying to publish to is using an insecure protocol (HTTP), which is not supported by default due to security reasons. Gradle is requiring the repository to use a secure protocol (HTTPS) to ensure the integrity and security of the artifacts being published.

```
plugins {
id 'java'
id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.2.RELEASE'
id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.8.RELEASE'
}
group 'com.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
publishing{
publications {
     maven(MavenPublication){
             artifact("build/libs/my-app-$version"+".jar")  {
                extension 'jar'
            }
     }
}
repositories {
    maven{
        name "nexus" //name of repo manager
        url "http://54.197.89.96:8081/repository/maven-snapshots/"
        setAllowInsecureProtocol(true)
        credentials{
            username project.repoUser
            password project.repoPassword
        }
    }
}
}
repositories {
mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
implementation group: 'net.logstash.logback', name: 'logstash-logback-encoder', version: '5.2'
testImplementation group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}
```